# Assign a request timeout for adobe air URLRequest and get the response without using eventListner

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Below code is used to read a file in the disk and upload as 1MB chunks to a php server via adobe AIR application. It iterates the do/while loop till the end of the file and uploading part is handled by **function getConnection**. The servers returns an XML as the response. With the eventListeners currently it goes to function onRequestComplete when it receives the response. Because of that issue current code exits the loop when it receives the response from the server. Is there any way that I can get the response of the request send by the **function getConnection** when it calling inside **function startUpload** ? also how can I define the request timeout for this single requests?

```
private function startUpload():void { 

var localFilePath:String =localFilesToUpload[currentUploadedVideoIndex].file.nativePath;
   var filePathArray = localFilePath.split("/");
   var uploadedFile:File = new File(localFilePath);
   var fileSize:Number = uploadedFile.size;
   var fileName:String = filePathArray[filePathArray.length-1];
   var fileId:String = "10";
   var index:Number=0;
   var chunkSize:Number=1024*1204;
   var size:Number=chunkSize;
   var serverPath:String = "http://myurl/rests";

   //encode username and password
   var userName:String="myusername";
   var password:String="mypassword";
   var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
   encoder.insertNewLines=false;
   encoder.encode(userName+":"+password);

   var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
   urlLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
   urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onRequestComplete);
   urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onResponceFail);

   var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(serverPath);
   urlRequest.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;



   do{
        //if this is true file must be uploaded as a chunk
        if(fileSize>chunkSize){
            if((index+size)>fileSize){ // if true this is the final chunk of the file.
                size = fileSize-index; // take the remaining size of the file
            }
        }else{
            size = fileSize; //this file can be uploaded directly 
        }

        //read the bytes from the file in the specified location
        var buff:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var uploadedFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        uploadedFileStream.open(uploadedFile,FileMode.READ);
        uploadedFileStream.readBytes(buff);
        uploadedFileStream.close();

        urlRequest.data=buff;


        //add the http headers to the file part and send 
        this.getConnection(urlRequest, urlLoader,encoder.toString(),fileSize,index,chunkSize,fileName,fileId,buff); 

    }while(index<fileSize)
  }
}


 private function getConnection(urlRequest:URLRequest, urlLoader:URLLoader ,authString:String, fileSize:Number, index:Number, chunkSize:Number, fileName:String, fileId:String, requestBody:ByteArray):void{

    //creates the relevent HTTP heaaders and assigned to parameters
    try{
        urlRequest.requestHeaders = parameters;
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
      }catch(error:Error){
        Alert.show(error.message);
    }
 }

 private function onRequestComplete(event:Event):String{
      var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
      Alert.show(loader.data,"Result");
 }

 private function onResponceFail(event:FaultEvent):void{
    Alert.show(event.message.toString(),"Fault");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you should check if operation is finished in `onRequestComplete` instead:

Pseudo code just to get you going:

```
function startUpload()
{
    // prepare big file
    ...
    // then start the uploading
    sendNextChunk();
}

function sendNextChunk()
{
    // grab the next chunk
    ...
    // and send it
    getConnection(...);
}

function onRequestComplete()
{
    // is there more chunks ?
    if (...more chunks?)
        sendNextChunk();
    else
        trace("All chunks uploaded");
}
```

Hope that helps,
Adnan